# If $\lim f(x) = 0,$ then $\lim 1/|f(x)| = \infty.$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

The Problem:

> Suppose that $f:D\to\Bbb R$, where $D$ is a subset of $\Bbb R$ and $a$ is an accumulation point of $D$, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0$, and $f(x)\ne0$ for any $x$ in $D$ in some neighborhood of $a$.  Prove that $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{1}{|f(x)|}= \infty$$

Right away, I noticed a similarity between a theorem involving sequences which stated that if $\lim_{n→∞}a_n=∞$, then $\lim_{n→∞}1/a_n=0$.  Another useful theorem: $\lim_{x→a}f(x)=L$ if and only if for every sequence $(x_n)_n$ in the domain $D$, $\lim_{n→∞}x_n=a$, where $a$ is a cluster point.

I could use some help trying to string these ideas together.

Comment: Let $N>0$ be arbitrary. Let $\varepsilon=1/N$ so there is a $\delta>0$ such that  $0<|x-a|<\delta$ imply $|f(x)|<1/N$. Since $f(x)\not=0$ thus $N<1/|f(x)|$.

Comment: Note that a function might approach a limit, but that limit doesn't approach anything.

Answer (score 1):

You almost want to start with the consequent/conclusion. That is, we want to show that $1/|f(x)|$ converges to infinity. To show that, we unwrap the definition of this as, for any sequence $a_n\to a$, for any $M$, there is $N$ such that for all $n>N$, we have $1/|f(a_n)|>M$.

Well, to prove this, we know that for any such sequence, we can guarantee that for any such sequence, and for any $\epsilon=1/M$, there is $N$ so that any $n>N$ gives $|f(a_n)|<\epsilon=1/M$. That shouldn't be hard to prove.

Some problems with this:

1. I gather your theorem is for $L$ finite, not $L=\infty$.
2. Your definition of converging to infinity may not involve sequences.
3. Your theorem about the reciprocal of a limit is going the wrong way, that is, it says $P\implies Q$ when you need something more like $Q\implies P$.

It is probably better to approach it with a straight forward $\epsilon-\delta$ proof. But you are right in that using the sequence version of checking limits is often easier to deal with.

Comment: So with your second paragraph, I would be showing that f(a_n) is bounded by 1/M. Does everything hold if I take the reciprocal of |f(a_n)|?

Comment: Well, we have to provide an argument that includes the "$f(x)\ne0$  for any $x$ in $D$  in some neighborhood of $a$." Really I would imagine the proof writing taking a few drafts to smooth out all the wrinkles. Have you decided to stick with the sequence strategy over an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof?

Comment: Actually, $D$ seems to be the entire domain, so really, we are guaranteed $f(x)\ne0$.