# If $\lim f(x) = 0,$ then $\lim 1/f(x) = \infty.$

Tags: limits

> Suppose that $f:D\to\Bbb R$, where $D$ is a subset of $\Bbb R$ and $a$ is an accumulation point of $D$, $\lim_{x\to a+}f(x)=0$, and $f(x)\ne0$ for any $x$ in $D$ in some neighborhood of $a$.
>   I understand from the following proof that if $\lim f(x) = 0,$ then $\lim 1/|f(x)| = \infty.$ : [proof for |f(x)|](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540924/if-lim-fx-0-then-lim-1-fx-infty),
>   however, does it also apply for $\lim 1/f(x)= \infty$ ? or $\lim 1/f(x)= -\infty$ If not then why?

Comment: What if $f$ only takes negative values?

Comment: the problem is whether you consider $\infty$ to be either $\pm \infty$ or only $+\infty$

Comment: What if $f$ takes both positive and negative values ($f$ would not be continuous)?

Comment: @MichaelBurr how can f take both of those, conjure to 0 and then not be continuous? when it's $\lim_{x\to a+}$?

Comment: @TheD0ubleT either, sorry, I edited it to be more clear on the matter

Comment: $f$ will be continuous at $a$, but it might not be a continuous function on all of $D$.  You could have a situation where it's jumping between positive and negative values, but getting closer to $0$ as $x$ approaches $a$.

Comment: @Yuki1112 Take thee continuous extension of $f(x) = \frac{sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x^2}$ to include $0$ in the domain.